# Library issue when running application

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I´m writing an application to test a library.
It compiles perfectly but when I run it on the virtual device (2.3.3), I get this error:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nicolas.luque/nicolas.luque.MyARActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nicolas.luque.MyARActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/nicolas.luque-2.apk]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nicolas.luque.MyARActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/nicolas.luque-2.apk]*

This is the activity code:

```
import es.ucm.look.ar.LookAR;
import es.ucm.look.data.EntityData;
import es.ucm.look.data.LookData;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyARActivity extends LookAR 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        EntityData data = new EntityData();
        data.setLocation(10, 0, 0);

        LookData.getInstance().getDataHandler().addEntity(data);

        LookData.getInstance().updateData();

    }

    public MyARActivity()
    {
        super(true, true, true, true, 100.0f, true);
    }
}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nicolas.luque"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyARActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have not idea what i´m doing wrong, it seems that my activity is missing. Anyone can help me??

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create libs folder in android project and just drag&drop the jar of your library to android project into libs folder. Build path will be automatically added and you can easily build and deploy. (Eclipse)